# Make the second car different random color JAVA

Tags: java, colors, graphics2d

I create every car whenever I clicked on screen but the second car dont change the color. I make the random color for my car but I dont know why the second car dont change. Please help me.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int red = randomGenerator.nextInt(256);
    int green = randomGenerator.nextInt(256);
    int blue = randomGenerator.nextInt(256);

     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

     if (drawCar) 
     {
         Color randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
         g2.setColor(randomColor);
         int x = 1;
         int carSpeed = 1;
         int w = getWidth(); 

        //create the car from draw class
         if (x == 1 )
         {
             x = lastX + carSpeed;
             if (x == w - 60)
             {
                 x = lastX - 730; 
             }
             lastX = x;
         }  

         Car car1 = new Car(x,320);
         car1.draw(g2);    

     }   
     if (drawCar2)
     {
         Color randomColor2 = new Color(red, green, blue);
         g2.setColor(randomColor2);
         int x = 1;
         int carSpeed = 1;
         int w = getWidth(); 

        //create the car from draw class
         if (x == 1 )
         {
             x = lastX2 + carSpeed;
             if (x == w - 60)
             {
                 x = lastX2 - 730; 
             }
             lastX2 = x;
         }  

         Car car2 = new Car(x,320);
         car2.draw(g2); 
     }

}
```

I think I might wrong in the g2 set Color but Its suppose to change the color. Or Java have any method to remove the current color ?

Answer (score 3):

When u call

```
Color randomColor2 = new Color(red, green, blue);
```

red, green and blue still have the same value.
u have to call your randomGenerator again.

```
red = randomGenerator.nextInt(256);
green = randomGenerator.nextInt(256);
blue = randomGenerator.nextInt(256);
Color randomColor2 = new Color(red, green, blue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you **do** change the color of `g` (theoretically). But you set it to identical colors:

```
Color randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue); //color for car 1

...//some other drawing stuff

Color randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue); //color for car 2
```

The values of `red`, `blue` and `green` never change, so neither does the color.